# jobs is not firing on heroku using hirefire

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, hirefire

i'm using gem "delayed_job_active_record" with hire fire on heroku to run jobs in background.i have also set heroku envirnoment variable using my heroku account. My sequence in gem file is below

```
   gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
   gem 'daemons'
   gem 'hirefire'
```

it is working in local envirnoment in development as production as well. But jobs not firing on heroku from delayed job table. First i try with no config file hirefire.rb in intilizer but no succes. After i add and put this code below.

```
           HireFire.configure do |config|

             if Rails.env.production?
              config.max_workers = 5 # default is 1
              config.min_workers = 0 # default is 0
              config.job_worker_ratio = [
               {:jobs => 1, :workers => 1},
               {:jobs => 15, :workers => 2},
               {:jobs => 35, :workers => 3},
               {:jobs => 60, :workers => 4},
               {:jobs => 80, :workers => 5}
              ]
        end
      end
```

but no success. Although hirefire is also loading see screen shot below also
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should probably not be doing check for `Rails.env.production?` there and put that in `config/environments/production.rb` instead.

To see how to setup delayed_job_active_record in Heroku, read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job